# bash script - exit status of previous command different if checked in a function

Tags: bash, shell

I don't get this - if I check the exit status of a command in a function and store in a local variable, I always get the answer 0. From outside the function, I get the correct exit status.

```
#!/bin/bash

function check_mysql()
{
    local output=`service mysql status`
    local mysql_status=$?

    echo "local output=$output"
    echo "local status=$mysql_status"
}

check_mysql

g_output=`service mysql status`
g_mysql_status=$?

echo "g output=$g_output"
echo "g status=$g_mysql_status"
```

Output is:

```
local output=MySQL is running but PID file could not be found..failed
local status=0
g output=MySQL is running but PID file could not be found..failed
g status=4
```

The status of 4 is the correct one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `local` command is run after the `service mysql status` command in your function. It is that which is returning 0. You are losing the return status of the `service` command.

Split the `local` statement into two:

```
local output
local mysql_status

output=`service mysql status`
mysql_status=$?
```